# Highcharts Highstock initial helper tooltips

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, highcharts

I'm using [multiple graphs](http://www.capecodbay-monitor.org/) which can be manipulated with the Highstock Navigator. (If you go to site, just click on an icon, then "Data and Graphs" modal button.)

After some recent feedback, I've been asked to provide some initial tooltips as most of the navigation methods aren't obvious to them. Something [like this](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/understanding-highstock) would be a great start. Really don't want to get into an animated tutorial.

I've used Bootstrap tooltips on other pages within text, but I'm clueless with providing them over the charts initially.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated,

thanks,

Michael

Comment: So you want the tooltip initially for the range selectors ? or you need to show a tooltip shown for some specific data-point on series as well ?

Comment: i just need initial tooltips for the navigation such as range selectors, date input, slider, etc.

Comment: Find DOM elements you want to use for tooltip/popover. Then follow [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12411500/show-twitter-bootstrap-tooltip-on-initalize) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12749859/load-a-twitter-bootstrap-popover-on-page-load).

Answer (score 0):

I found this plugin, [Bootstrap Tour](http://bootstraptour.com/). It worked out nicely, easy to implement and good docs.

```
var tour = new Tour();
tour.addSteps([
    {
        element: "#container1 .highcharts-series-group",
        title: "Click and Drag",
        content: "Click anywhere within chart and drag...",
        placement: 'top'
   },
   {
        element: "#container1 .highcharts-legend",
        title: "Toggle Parameters",
        content: "Click on any parameter to toggle on and off",
        placement: 'bottom'
   },
   {
        element: ".highcharts-range-selector-buttons",
        title: "Range Selector",
        content: "Click on zoom range to view that data",
        placement: 'bottom'
   },
   {
       element: ".highcharts-input-group",
       title: "Date Range",
       content: "Enter any valid date range",
       placement: 'bottom'
   },
   {
       element: ".highcharts-navigator",
       title: 'Navigator Slide Bar',
       content: 'Drag slidebar to desired time period',
       placement: 'bottom'
   }
]);
```

After HighCharts page loads:

```
$('#container1').highcharrts('StockChart...);
tour.init(true);
tour.start(true);
```

From docs:
Please note: By default, this will run the tour only once in your browser. So if you want to see it every time for debugging purpose, please use:

```
// Force initialize the tour 
tour.init(true); 

// Force start the tour 
tour.start(true);
```

any comments and suggestions are always welcome. [Provincetown Center for Coastal Studies](http://www.capecodbay-monitor.org/)